# For a compactly supported, continuously differentiable function $f$, do we have $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\to f'(x)$ uniformly?

Tags: analysis

For a compactly supported, continuously differentiable function $f$, do we have $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\to f'(x)$ uniformly? (Euclidean space)

I think this is true, since compact supported-ness is pretty strong condition and this is geometrically clear. But I'm not sure how to prove it. Could someone help?

Comment: Yes, $f$ being $C^1$ and $f$ being compactly supported imply that $f'$ is a compactly supported continuous function, hence uniformly continuous. Write out what this means, and you can see (via the mean-value theorem) that you have uniform convergence.

Comment: How is uniform continuity and uniform convergence related? Is it like a common strategy when proving uniform convergence, to show that it is uniformly continuous first?

Comment: I don't think so, but here you'll see how to apply it once you write out the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions and apply the MVT: $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\right|=|f'(\xi_{h,x})-f'(x)|$ for some point $\xi_{h,x}$ between $x$ and $x+h$. Now, how can we upper bound $|f'(\xi_{h,x})-f'(x)|$ in a manner such that the upper bound doesn't depend on $x$? Uniform continuity of $f'$ is perfect here.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you! It seems that the supported-ness is irrelevant here? I mean it is enough that f be defined on a compact set. At first the setup seems to be very similar to Dini's theorem so I was thinking of using supported-ness but I couldn't think of MVT

Comment: well, this proof is really just using that $f'$ is uniformly continuous; compact support of $f$ is a slight red herring. One could slightly generalize the statement of the theorem to say "If $f$ is continuously differentiable on an interval $I$ (say open), then the difference quotient converges to $f'$ uniformly on compact subsets of $I$", where the idea of proof is identical; the only extra step is that continuous functions ($f'$) on compact sets are uniformly continuous, so it's an extra topological fact.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks so much!